# IOKit: Not receiving HID interrupt reports from DualShock 4 controller connected with Bluetooth

Tags: macos, iokit, gamepad

**Introduction**

I am working on getting full support for the `PlayStation 4 Controller` using the HID interface in `IOKit`. The controller is connected over `Bluetooth`.  I can open a connection to the controller and start receiving reports, however, once I send it a report it suddenly stops.

In order to get full control over the PS4 controller (rumble, trackpad, LEDs), I've been referencing [the eleccelerator.com DualShock 4 page](http://eleccelerator.com/wiki/index.php?title=DualShock_4#Bluetooth) which contains information about the reports that can/are sent between the PS4 and DS4.

**Code**

First, I create an `IOHIDManager` which is responsible for detecting controllers.

```
self.hidManager = IOHIDManagerCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);
// Make sure we detect ANY type of 'game controller'
NSArray *criteria = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
        CreateCriterion(kHIDPage_GenericDesktop, kHIDUsage_GD_Joystick),
        CreateCriterion(kHIDPage_GenericDesktop, kHIDUsage_GD_GamePad),
        CreateCriterion(kHIDPage_GenericDesktop, kHIDUsage_GD_MultiAxisController),
    nil];

IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatchingMultiple(self.hidManager, (__bridge CFArrayRef)criteria);

IOHIDManagerScheduleWithRunLoop(self.hidManager, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
IOHIDManagerOpen(self.hidManager, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);

// Register callbacks
IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceMatchingCallback(self.hidManager, ControllerConnected, (__bridge void *)self);
IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceRemovalCallback(self.hidManager, ControllerDisconnected, (__bridge void *)self);
```

Then after getting a call to `ControllerConnected`, I create an instance of a joystick class, which initializes the `IOHIDDeviceRef`.

```
- (void)registerDevice:(IOHIDDeviceRef)device {
    self.device = device;

    // Initialize the buffer
    self.receivedPacketMaxSize = 552; // When using Bluetooth
    self.receivedReport = (uint8_t *)calloc(self.receivedPacketMaxSize, sizeof(uint8_t));

    // Register the device report callback
    IOHIDDeviceScheduleWithRunLoop(self.device, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    IOHIDDeviceRegisterInputReportCallback(self.device, self.receivedReport, self.receivedPacketMaxSize, ControllerReport, (__bridge void *)self);

    self.isValid = YES;
}
```

Now I DO get calls to `ControllerReport`, however the reports I receive are of type [0x01](http://eleccelerator.com/wiki/index.php?title=DualShock_4#0x01) which are limited in what they contain (the do not have trackpad or accelerometer data), but I want to receive the packets of type [0x11](http://eleccelerator.com/wiki/index.php?title=DualShock_4#0x11) which contain all of the data from the controller.

In order to switch which packet the controller sends, the website states `This report is sent once the GET REPORT FEATURE 0x02 is received.`  So I send that request:

```
CFIndex len = self.receivedPacketMaxSize;
IOReturn featureMode2RequestError = IOHIDDeviceGetReport(self.device, kIOHIDReportTypeFeature, 0x02, self.receivedReport, &len);
if (featureMode2RequestError != kIOReturnSuccess) {
    NSLog(@"Could switch the controller to mode 2 :(");
}
```

At this point, `ControllerReport` stops being called with new reports from the controller.

I know I'm able to send data to the controller because I'm able to send a packet that changes the LED color, or sets the rumble speed.

**Question**

How can I get the longer 0x11 reports from the PS4 Controller?

**What I've Tried**

I've tried using `IOHIDDeviceGetReportWithCallback` and `IOHIDDeviceGetReport`, but I always get `kIOReturnUnsupported` back.

I've also found some reference to this problem inside of the source of a linux driver for the controller in the form of `... it starts sending input reports in report 17.  Since report 17 is undefined ...`, however I don't know how to tell IOKit to handle report 17 (0x11).

Comment: I can't tell you why you're seeing that specific problem and how to fix it, but if I was debugging this, I'd check the [IOKit HID family](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/IOHIDFamily/IOHIDFamily-606.1.7/) and [IOKit userlib HID](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/IOKitUser/IOKitUser-1050.1.21/hid.subproj/) source code and trace the path of the device's reports. Once you've found the spot where they're being ignored, it shouldn't be too hard to work around it.

Comment: I do now yet have a solution.  Since it seems that this is cause by a bug in the framework, I will be giving it another try in the fall when macOS is released. However I doubt I will have the resources to find and fix the issue if it still exists then.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that IOHIDDeviceGetReport kIOHIDReportTypeOutput sends output reports over the interrupt endpoint; the DS4 expects it via the control endpoint. AFAIK there isn't any way on OS X to do a output GetReport via the ctrl endpoint (short of writing a kext to override it).